# What is the difference between alarm_start and alarm_start_relative?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

What is the difference between `alarm_start` and `alarm_start_relative`? The functions are in `alarmtimers.h` in Linux Kernel.

Thanks

Comment: `alarm_start` parameter `start` is absolute time, and `alarm_start_relative` parameter `start` is relative time (absolute time = relative time + base)

Comment: Voting to close : "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.". Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs. Tnx